# eclipse hides/blocks text near cursor

Tags: eclipse, cursor

I am having ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and eclipse.

when i try to click on the editor(any editor, java or xml), eclipse blocks/hides the text near the cursor.

let me explain with the pictures.

below is the part of xml file i am trying to edit.

[image]

When I click on the text ***entry key="json" value="application/json"***, it blocks the letters nearby cursor, as shown in image below :

[image]

in the above image, the cursor is between ***value*** and ***=***, like ***value{cursor}=***, but i am not able to see the cursor, and also not able to see some characters near the cursor.

However when I try to click on different line, the previously blocked text becomes visible but the characters nearby new cursor position gets blocked, for example when i click near ***property name="mediaTypes"***, exactly my cursor is like ***property name="me{cursor}diaTypes"***, but what eclipse shows me is shown in below image.[image]

first I thought that it may be the problem with eclipse(juno), so i removed the eclipse installation, and downloaded new eclipse(kepler), but still the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved :

I updated the ubuntu to latest version and the issue is gone.

But the mystery remails unsolved, why it was blocking texts near cusrsor.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Right-Click->Input Methods-> (Simple or IBus or X Input Method)**. Seemed to work for me. Hope it helped :)